# Javascript Window.Open: Chrome is not honoring Toolbars , back/forth navigation buttons

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-chrome, window.open

I have the latest Version of Chrome Version 86.0.4240.111 in 2020.
When I run a Window.Open command in Typescript Angular, its not honoring the toolbars. I need the back/forth navigation buttons. How can I make Chrome follow this?

```
const strWindowFeatures = `location=yes,height=${screen.height},width=${screen.width},fullscreen=yes,toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes`;
var newWindow = window.open('http://www.cnn.com', 'test', strWindowFeatures);
newWindow.moveTo(0, 0);
```

[image]

No Back and forth arrows above

Comment: Shouldn't it be `toolbar` instead of `toolbars`?

Comment: hi @MichałTkaczyk mistyped question, its still not working

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot of your newly opened window? I'm curious how does it look like.

Comment: added cc @MichałTkaczyk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MDN window.open#Toolbar_and_UI_parts_features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Toolbar_and_UI_parts_features):

> In modern browsers (Firefox 76 or newer, Google Chrome, Safari, Chromium Edge), the following features are just a condition for whether to open popup or not. See popup condition section.

And according to [popup condition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Popup_condition):

> Most modern browsers (listed below) don't allow web content to control the visibility of UI parts separately.
>
> - Firefox 76 or newer
> - Google Chrome
> - Safari
> - Chromium Edge
>
> UI-related items of windowFeatures are used as a condition to whether opening a popup or a new tab, or a new window, and UI parts visibility of each of them is fixed.
>
> The condition is implementation-depepdent and not guaranteed to be stable.

So, what I guess is that you are opening a popup and, for this reason, Google Chrome does not allow showing other chrome's elements out of the navigation bar. This probably to distinguish a popup from a new tab.

Passing these options to `window.open` will make a popup being created instead of a normal tab, but it seems some of them are not really used if not for the reason above.

- menubar
- toolbar
- location
- status
- resizable
- scrollbars

Hope this will be useful to you.

Comment: so whats the solution then?

Comment: I don't think there's one actually. What I think is that this specification is a pretty old thing that has not been updated to today's usages and cases (popups were more tolerated than now, for example), so I don't think it is actually reliable (like many other browser-dependent things). I might be wrong, anyway.